# User is unable to perform inline editing without using the edit quick action on the product record page

Tags: page-layout, lightning-record-page

Recently we introduced the lightning record page as the default view on the standard product object. Post this change we are not seeing any option of inline editing for the fields on this record page. User have to click on the edit quick action in the highlights panel to edit records. There have been no updates to the OLS and FLS at both the profile and permission set levels.

FYI, even on the lightning record page we are just using the standard elements no custom components or elements have been added.

Can someone please share some inputs how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is known functionality gap. In lightning  if you want to edit the Product records you have to use EDIT quick action only, Inline editing is not possible as of now.

Please find the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdawGUAR/inline-editing-for-products-in-lightning) posted for the same.